# Need a SQL Server query to eliminate the Highlighted Rows ( Returning Routes in Flight)

Tags: sql, sql-server, google-bigquery

I have a requirement where I need to eliminate all the rows which have returning flight routes.

I have highlighted the routes in the orange color which depicts this behavior.

For example, row 1 has one route `BKI - MYY` and row 4 has `MYY - BKI`. I need a flag (Boolean 1/0) that checks the entire row and sees if it's a returning flight or not.

Note: there are a few scenarios where the flight started at 10:00 PM night today and returned the next day early morning. if it is a consecutive day then we need to eliminate that rows as well.

Any thought on how to solve this?

**Gsheet link** : Sample Data : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ibrUfOTMEx4i-erDQnIfszdcEvJKU_oFcnMBFcGbvyM/edit?usp=sharing

**Definition:** Return flight is a two-way journey by air. If a flight is starting from the source and after certain hop/route returns backs to the same source (Departure Station)

**std_utc** = Departure Time
**Sta_utc** = Arival Time

[image]

```
with AllFlight as
(
select row_number()over(order by std_utc)rn, aoc,hub,flight ,departure,arrival,std_utc,sta_utc
from TABLENAME01
),
returnFlight as 
(
select * from AllFlight s
where exists 
(
    select * from AllFlight s2 
    where s2.rn<s.rn and s2.arrival=s.departure and s2.departure=s.arrival 
    and 
    (date_diff(EXTRACT(DATE FROM s.sta_utc),EXTRACT(DATE FROM s2.std_utc), DAY))<=1
)
)

select aoc,hub,flight ,departure ,arrival,std_utc  ,sta_utc from AllFlight where rn not in (select rn from returnFlight)
```

This query is kept on running and not giving me the desired output.
Note: I am using Bigquery

Comment: Don't link to off site resources to supply sample data; if you want to supply sample data put it in your question as DDL and DML statements (or tabular foramtted `text`). Also, have you made *any* attempts to resolve this yourself? What were they? Otherwise, what was the research you performed to try to resolve this yourself and what about the resources you read didn't you understand?

Comment: To answer your question, I am using bigquery so  standard SQL code will work in my case so that the reason I opted SQL server or Bigquery. I tried using Tableau formatted for adding the Table but the output is a little messed up which might leads to confusion. In addition to that, I have done enough research not here but On another website as well but I didn't find anything useful so asking questions here. I haven't added any code because it is not giving me the correct output and I am nowhere close to what I am expecting.hope this clarify all the question.

Comment: Perhaps YOU understand the term "returning flight" but you don't provide any rules for matching. You also seem to have some idea (or assumption) of which direction defines the originating flight and which defines the returning flight. Difficult to help without better understanding of your model and your goals.

Comment: You can still "fix" it by providing more information and responding to all of the suggesions, questions, and issues raised. It can be re-opened. But the downvotes are a good indication that you need to put more effort into your question. And your clarifications, answers should go into the body of your question, not in comments. No offense, but a "senior" anything should be able to accept criticism and improve their question. And nope - not gonna open a link like you posted.

Comment: Is there any unique key column in this table?

Comment: @RajeevPandey Third row is also a return flight of first row why that is not included in exclude list please explain.

Comment: Thanks for the question. The Date is different for that flight so that's a separate row. For First date, we have 4 entries and for 3rd Date, we have only two enteries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a table named **S65828793** with your provided data. First I have numbered the rows in ascending sequence of departure time. Then from that I have identified the flights that have been another flight within two consecutive days from opposite direction and marked those as returning flight.
Then at last I have excluded all the returning flight from the total flight list.

```
with AllFlight as (
select row_number()over(order by departuretime)rn, aoc  ,hub    ,flight ,departure  ,arrival    ,DepartureTime  ,ArrivalTime from S65828793  
),
returnFlight as (select * from AllFlight s
where exists (select * from AllFlight s2 where s2.rn<s.rn and s2.arrival=s.departure and s2.departure=s.arrival and datediff(day,cast(s.ArrivalTime as date),cast(s2.departuretime as date))<=1))
select aoc  ,hub    ,flight ,departure  ,arrival    ,DepartureTime  ,ArrivalTime from AllFlight where rn not in (select rn from returnFlight)
```

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: Hi Ali, As I am using Bigquery so I have modified the query to fit my need but its keeps on running and ran for 15 min and I had to cancel the query to avoid any cost. I am not using a large volume of data but I am not sure what is causing an issue, it may be "Exist" so I am trying to change it to Join. 
Additionally,
I am not sure how to add comments on code so I attached it with my question. Please have a look